# Unable to use latex in inkscape

Tags: python, latex, inkscape

I am trying to use latex in inkscape but it is not working. I installed all the required packages (e.g inkscape-version 1.0.2, texlive-base, pdflatex,  pdf2svg, python-lxml , python-gi). The operating system of my computer is Ubuntu 18.04

But when i launch letex in inkscape using the procedures extensions>render>text with latex(GTK3) I get the following error printed on the screen.

Is there anyone who can help me solve this problem please?

```
kscape has received additional data from the script executed. the script did not return an error but this may indicate results will not be as expected

/home/joha/.config/inkscape/extensions/latextext.py:639: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or `optparse` has been deprecated and replaced with `argparser`.You must change `self.OptionParser.add_option` to `self.arg_parser.add_argument`; the arguments are similar.
  add_options(self.OptionParser)

/home/joha/.config/inkscape/extensions/latextext.py:640: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or `optparse` has been deprecated and replaced with `argparser`.You must change `self.OptionParser.add_option` to `self.arg_parser.add_argument`; the arguments are similar.
  self.OptionParser.set_conflict_handler("resolve")

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py:13: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
  import fnmatch, glob, traceback, errno, sys, atexit, locale, imp, stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "latextext_gtk3.py", line 176, in <module>
    effect = RenderLatexEffectGTK3()
  File "/home/joha/.config/inkscape/extensions/latextext.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.OptionParser.set_conflict_handler("resolve")
AttributeError: 'RenderLatexEffectGTK3' object has no attribute 'set_conflict_handler'
```

```
$ which inkscape
```

outputs `/usr/bin/inkscape` and

```
$  apt-cache policy inkscape
```

outputs

```
  Installed: 1.0.2+r75+1~ubuntu18.04.1 
  Candidate: 1.0.2+r75+1~ubuntu18.04.1 
  Version table: 
*** 1.0.2+r75+1~ubuntu18.04.1 500 
      500 ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages 
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 0.92.3-1 
      500 500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please show the output of `which inkscape` and `apt-cache policy inkscape` .

Comment: which inkscape  outputs  /usr/bin/inkscape                                   and apt-cache policy inkscape  outputs    Installed: 1.0.2+r75+1~ubuntu18.04.1
  Candidate: 1.0.2+r75+1~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2+r75+1~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.92.3-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to remove local extension installation by

```
rm /home/joha/.config/inkscape/extensions/latextext.py
```

Then you have two options:

- to use preinstalled *LaTeX (pdflatex)* (Inkscape, Extensions → Mathematics → LaTeX (pdflatex)) with already installed Inkscape from PPA

  you need to install dependencies and previous version of Inkscape:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install texlive pstoedit
  ```
- to use preinstalled LaTeX extension (Inkscape, Extensions → Render → LaTeX)

  you need to install dependencies and previous version of Inkscape:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install texlive pstoedit
  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
  sudo ppa-purge ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
  ```

.

Comment: I have followed your steps but i still get error below    /home/joha/.config/inkscape/extensions/latextext.py:639: DeprecationWarning: Effect.OptionParser or `optparse` has been deprecated and replaced with `argparser`.You must change `self.OptionParser.add_option` to `self.arg_parser.add_argument`; the arguments are similar ..................... the error continues can't put it all here because it exceeds the required number of characters

Comment: See update above, the Inkscape from PPA does not support LaTeX.

Comment: Unfortunately i have followed your advice but still it can't work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Ubunutu 23.04 with Inkscape 1.3. The fix for me was to:

- update OS from 23.04 to 23.10
- sudo apt remove inkscape texlive pstoedit
- sudo apt install inkscape texlive pstoedit
- sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra

Now writing expressions with Extensions>Render>formula(pdflatex) works fine.